# How do I, in a macro, yank a word which might be just one letter long?

Tags: cursor-movement, macro

I am writing a macro a part of which is supposed to extract verse numbers from a string such as `11.1`, standing for "verse one in canto eleven". I search `/11\.\zs`. The cursor now is in the right place. Now if I have a one-digit verse number, I'd just select it by `v`, then yank it `y`. Fine. But that works only for the first nine verses of each canto, normally it the number I need to yank will be two digits, sometimes three digits long. Also fine, `ve`, BUT, then it doesn't work with one-digit verse numbers, as that will go to the end of the NEXT WORD, producing a very different effect from what I had in mind. How would I catch both the cases with the same key-stroke sequence?

Probably I'd just include the dot into the to-be-yanked word, and then later get rid of it, as that seems to work, or is there a more elegant way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Using simply `yw` or `yiw` (not in Visual mode) works. Also `viw` (to select "inside word") followed by `y` will work too.

Comment: @filbranden `yw` will include the space after the word, but `yiw` seems to be doing what is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`iw`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#iw) text object to select the current word only.

From [`:help iw`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#iw):

> `iw`: "inner word", select `[count]` words (see `word`). White space between words is counted too. When used in Visual linewise mode `iw` switches to Visual characterwise mode.

White space counts between words, but only when more than one word is selected.

You can either use it in Visual mode, by using `viw` followed by `y`, or just directly as a text object with `yiw`.